# Open Android call log inside my activity

Tags: android, logging, call

I do not know if this is possible to achieve:

I am developing and android app for the place I work at. The user is will not be able to use anything else but the app.

The problem that I am facing is that I need to get a call log for the user to see the missed calls, I was planning to use the OS call log screen, but I want to know if I can open that call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open the standard Android call log

[image]

Fire a Calls.CONTENT_TYPE intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivity(i);
```

To programmatically get call log records from database (e.g. to populate your own UI):

```
Cursor cur = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
int numberInd = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
int typeInd = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
int dateInd = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
int durationInd = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

while (cur.moveToNext()) {
     String number = cur.getString(numberInd);
     String type = cur.getString(typeInd);
     String date = cur.getString(dateInd);
     String duration = cur.getString(durationInd);
     int callCode = Integer.parseInt(type);
     // callCode can be OUTGOING_TYPE, INCOMING_TYPE or MISSED_TYPE

     .........
}
```

And in both cases you will need a READ_CALL_LOG permission

Comment: Thanks, for the help, @Gilad!

Tho I want to know if I can open that screen inside an activity made by me.

Comment: see changes in orig post